# Why can't I store string keys in an Associative Array?

Tags: string, d, associative-array

I'm new to D programming language, just started reading The D Programming Language book.

I run into error when trying one associative array example code

```
#!/usr/bin/rdmd
import std.stdio, std.string;

void main() {
    uint[string] dict;
    foreach (line; stdin.byLine()) {
        foreach (word; splitter(strip(line))) {
            if (word in dict) continue;
            auto newId = dict.length;
            dict[word] = newId;
            writeln(newId, '\t', word);
        }   
    }   
}
```

DMD shows this Error message:

> ./vocab.d(11): Error: associative arrays can only be assigned values with immutable keys, not char[]

I'm using DMD compile 2.051

I was guessing the rules for associative arrays has changed since the TDPL book.

How should I use Associative arrays with string keys?

Thanks.

Update:

I found the solution in later parts of the book.

use string.idup to make a duplicate immutable value before putting into the array.

so

```
dict[word.idup] = newId;
```

would do the job.

But is that efficient ?

Comment: FYI for anyone coming to this question months or years later - there are other things wrong with the example as printed.  Use ulong not uint for the type of associative array, and you need to import std.array to get the splitter.  See http://www.digitalmars.com/d/archives/digitalmars/D/learn/problems_with_DPL_example._30009.html

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Associative arrays require that their keys be immutable. It makes sense when you think about the fact that if it's not immutable, then it might change, which means that its hash changes, which means that when you go to get the value out again, the computer won't find it. And if you go to replace it, you'll end up with another value added to the associative array (so, you'll have one with the correct hash and one with an incorrect hash). However, if the key is immutable, it cannot change, and so there is no such problem.

Prior to dmd 2.051, the example worked (which was a [bug](http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=2954)). It has now been fixed though, so the example in TDPL is no longer correct. However, it's not so much the case that the rules for associative arrays have changed as that there was a bug in them which was not caught. The example compiled when it shouldn't have, and Andrei missed it. It's listed in the [official errata for TDPL](http://erdani.com/tdpl/errata/index.php?title=Main_Page) and should be fixed in future printings.

The corrected code should use either `dictionary[word.idup]` or `dictionary[to!string(word)]`. `word.idup` creates a duplicate of `word` which is immutable. `to!string(word)`, on the other hand converts `word` to a `string` in the most appropriate manner. As `word` is a `char[]` in this case, that would be to use `idup`. However, if `word` were already a `string`, then it would simply return the value which was passed in and not needlessly copy it. So, in the general case, `to!string(word)` is the better choice (particularly in templated functions), but in this case, either works just fine (`to!()` is in `std.conv`).

It is technically possible to cast a `char[]` to a `string`, but it's generally a bad idea. If you *know* that the `char[]` will never change, then you can get away with it, but in the general case, you're risking problems, since the compiler will then assume that the resulting `string` can never change, and it could generate code which is incorrect. It may even segfault. So, don't do it unless profiling shows that you really need the extra efficiency of avoiding the copy, you can't otherwise avoid the copy by doing something like just using a `string` in the first place (so no conversion would be necessary), and you *know* that the `string` will never be changed.

In general, I wouldn't worry too much of the efficiency of copying strings. Generally, you should be using `string` instead of `char[]`, so you can copy them around (that is copy their reference around (e.g. `str1 = str2;`) rather than copying their entire contents like `dup` and `idup` do) without worrying about it being particularly inefficient. The problem with the example is that `stdin.byLine()` returns a `char[]` rather than a `string` (presumably to avoid copying the data if its not necessary). So, `splitter()` returns a `char[]`, and so `word` is a `char[]` instead of a `string`. Now, you could do `splitter(strip(line.idup))` or `splitter(strip(line).idup)` instead of `idup`ing the key. That way, `splitter()` would return a `string` rather than `char[]`, but that's probably essentially just as efficient as `idup`ing `word`. Regardless, because of where the text is coming from originally, it's a `char[]` instead of a `string`, which forces you to `idup` it somewhere along the line if you intend to use it as a key in an associative array. In the general case, however, it's better to just use `string` and not `char[]`. Then you don't need to `idup` anything.

**EDIT:**
Actually, even if you find a situation where casting from `char[]` to `string` seems both safe and necessary, consider using `std.exception.assumeUnique()` ([documentation](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/phobos/std_exception.html#assumeUnique)). It's essentially the preferred way of converting a mutable array to an immutable one when you need to and know that you can. It would typically be done in cases where you've constructed an array which you couldn't make immutable because you had to do it in pieces but which has no other references, and you don't want to create a deep copy of it. It wouldn't be useful in situations like the example that you're asking about though, since you really do need to copy the array.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and insightful answer! Now I've got the point of string and char[]. Thanks very much!

Comment: +1, great answer. Coming back to D after a long hiatus, only to find that the 2.047 compiler has moved on a bit!

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not efficient, since it obviously duplicates the string. If you can *guarantee* that the string you create will *never* be modified in memory, feel free to explicitly use a cast `cast(immutable)str` on it, instead of duplicating it.

(Although, I've noticed that the garbage collector works well, so I suggest you don't actually try that unless you see a bottleneck, since you might decide to change the string later. Just place a comment in your code to help you find the bottleneck later, if it exists.)

Comment: In this example, the extra idup isn't a performance issue because it's the result of avoiding extra allocations in the file input code. As a result you are just paying the same cost you would elsewhere if you tried to avoid the idup there.